# Image downloader beautifulsoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I made a script for my friend in python(I lost the bet),which download all of the thumbnail images(about 50 imgs,one img size is 20 kB) by data-thumb_url tag in which are urls.

Can this code can break the website or affect on it badly(I mean DDOS or smth like that)?I used it few times for 10,20,30 imgs and it works perfectly,and website works normal too(it is very popular website,one of the most in the world and it wasn't said that webscraping is illegal in this website),but I need to know if it's safe code.

```
from PIL import Image
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests 
import os
url = '' #(here is the url of website)
response = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
images = soup.find_all('img')
listt = []
for i in images:
    try:
        listt.append(i['data-thumb_url'])
    except KeyError:
        pass 
for i in range(len(listt)):
    img = Image.open(requests.get(listt[i], stream = True).raw)
    img.save("image"+str(i)+".jpg")
```

I know that it's a little bit silly question considering 80-100 millions of website views per day,and for example free extensions/websites/programs to download images from website,but I'm new in bs and requests in Python + I'm anxious.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, in the code you provided, you the list of URLs as `listt` in most places, but you call it `lista` when appending.

Secondly, no, your code isn't going to break a website.  Because you are just running a Python in a single thread, it will only make 1 request at a time.  If you wanted to be super cautious, you can add a `time.sleep` inside your last `for` loop, but that isn't really necessary.

Answer (score 1):

If you are accessing multiple urls, even with the sleep, the site might have other security  measures that you might trigger (prove you are a human). This might cause your script to fail when you try accessing other pages...

Without seeing the site you are hitting and the number of pages, it is hard to say for certain. But Cargo23 is right, as it stands now,you wont be breaking the site anytime soon.

Comment: So how does the extensions for browser 'Download all Images' works?Or sites like this?They're accessing to URLs too.My script is searching for imgs in one tag,not all of the imgs from websites like extensions do and other sites made to do that do,so there is less requests i think.

Comment: It probably works in a similar fashion. On the page, they are looking for the `img` tag and downloading the `src` listed.

I don't know of any add-on that crawls every page on a site and rips the images; they only look at a specific page. That is why @Cargo23 said it is ok since you are only going to one page. 

You could make a list of pages that are iterated over in a threaded fashion (each processor is acting independently). This would be much more suspicious behavior.